# How can I update the loadUrl of a WebView from another class

Tags: java, android, webview

I've create a WebView in the main class of an activity, then I've a new class but I can't modify any property of the webView created in the main class, what are the steps for the proper update?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation i would probably create an interface. Then in the class that extends WebView or whatnot, you could call loadUrl from the interface. Then from another class you could call the interface method inside of the class that extends WebView. If you need an example let me know and i can provide one.

More on interfaces:

[Oracle Documentation on Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)
[Oracle Documentation on how to implement intefaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html)