# LoadURL in WebViewFragment from another class?

Tags: android, webview, fragment

I have a class which extends `WebViewFragment` and what I want to achieve is to be able to load other URL from another class into this `WebViewFragment` class. Here is how my code looks like:

```
public class FragWeber extends WebViewFragment {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        WebView webView = getWebView();
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Any idea how to access the `WebView` to load other URL?

Comment: can u explain bit more?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874720/how-can-i-update-the-loadurl-of-a-webview-from-another-class?rq=1

Comment: @SathishKumarJ I have a class which extends activity and this class which extends WebViewFragment, my goal  is to able to load URL from the activity class with a click of button into the WebViewFragment class.

Comment: @momo it is kind of, but I can't get i to work i need someone to provide me an example..

Answer (score 0):

```
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            String url1 = url;  // can add your URL address
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: means you need to load the url in webview when clicks on some button inside same activity??

Comment: means on click on a button inside activity you wants to redirect to second activity having webview will load some url?

Comment: Yeah exactly from the `MainActivity` onClick of a button to load a URL into the `FragWeber`.

Comment: why you are using WebViewFragment for that. You can create a simple activity for the same. And Just pass the intent to start that activity from your MainActivity.

Comment: I know that but i read somewhere using interface it can be achieved so i thought i will try but without success...

Comment: i have not used the webViewFragment yet. That's good to try new things. Good Luck